# About non-decreasing and right continuous functions

Tags: measure-theory

I'm preparing my first test of the semester and I have a doubt. Is true that if $\mu$  is a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure, then exists a function $F:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ non-decreasing and right continuos such that $\mu=\mu_F$, where $\mu_F((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$?

If someone can give me a hand I would really appreciate it

Comment: What about function $F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$?

Comment: @iiivooo: In general, that will only work if $\mu$ is a finite measure.

Comment: @PhoemueX yes you are right, but I doubt the the theorem holds if the measure is not finite.